# XPath concat() does not return multiple items

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML file. 
I am writing an XPath query to return the concatenation of `fname` and `weight` for all orders with `weight>50`.

```
<purple> 
    <customer cid="1">
        <fname>John</fname> 
        <lname>Klingard</lname> 
        <apt>27</apt> 
        <street>30th Winstonhut St.</street> 
        <pobox>199183</pobox> 
    </customer>

    <customer cid="2"> 
        <fname>Anthony</fname> 
        <lname>Hurro</lname> 
        <apt>86</apt> 
        <street>Town St.</street> 
        <pobox>177162</pobox> 
    </customer> 

    <order oid="1"> 
        <eta>2016-04-23</eta> 
        <weight>55</weight> 
        <custid>1</custid>
    </order>

    <order oid="2"> 
        <eta>2016-05-03</eta> 
        <weight>75</weight> 
        <custid>2</custid> 
    </order>  
</purple>
```

I have written the query as:

```
concat(
 /purple/customer[@cid=/purple/order[weight>50]/custid]/fname/text(),
 /purple/order[weight>50]/weight/text())
```

The output is:

```
John55
```

The desired output is:

```
John55
Anthony75
```

Any advice on how I can achieve this?

Comment: with xpath 1.0 you can't get more then one result, when use string functions

Comment: @splash58 Yes, I understand. I found out that I need to use the '|' operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XPath 1.0

XPath 1.0 cannot return multiple string concatenations like you request.  Your output is closer to a rearrangement than a pure selection, so you should consider XSLT.

### XPath 2.0

**You can use a `for` loop in XPath 2.0:**

```
for $c in /purple/customer[@cid=/purple/order[weight>50]/custid]
    return concat($c/fname, /purple/order[custid=$c/@cid]/weight)
```

**will return**

```
John55
Anthony75
```

**as requested**

Comment: This is interesting! I did manage to get close to the required output by using the '|' operator. Like this: purple/customer[@cid=/purple/order[weight>50]/custid]/fname/text() | purple/order[weight>50]/weight/text()

Comment: Well, your XPath will return four text nodes, `John, Anthony, 55, 75`, not even in the requested order, so I'm not sure that qualifies as "close".  You could probably enumerate them out and rearrange for some predetermined cases but would be hard pressed to generalize the approach when the needed number is not known in advance.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Is the execution always from left-to-right for the '|' operator?

Comment: The union operator (`|`) returns its results in *document order*.  So, your same XPath would return `55, 75, John, Anthony` if the `order` elements all came before the `customer` elements in the XML document.